# Picard-Lindelöf theorem variations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

There are so many slight variations of this theorem around. I wrote the following in my own words from different sources online in a way that makes sense to me. Is what I have written accurate? I want to make sure I have understood the theorem correctly.

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^m$ containing $(t_0,y_0)$ and let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$. If $f$ is continuous in $t$ and satisfies for some $K\geqslant 0$, $|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|\leqslant K\,|x-y|$ for every $x,y \in U$. Then for some $\tau >0$ there exists a unique solution $y(t)$ on the interval $[t_0 - \tau, t_0 +\tau]$ for the initial value problem
$$y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), \,\,\,\,\, y(t_0)=y_0$$

Comment: I think $U$ should be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most general statements are:

- Peano: $f$ is continuous on $U$, then a local solution to the IVP exists.
- Picard-Lindelöf - local variant: $f$ is continuous on $U$ and is locally Lipschitz in $y$ direction (for instance if $f$ is continuously differentiable in that direction), then a local solution to the IVP exists and is unique.

Where the idea of a local solution is as you wrote. Then there is

- Picard-Lindelöf - global variant: If $U=(a,b)\times \Bbb R^n$ and $f$ is continuous with a global Lipschitz condition in $y$ direction, then a global solution $y:(a,b)\to\Bbb R^n$ exists and is unique.

As you can see, I avoided the naming of constants in the theorem, as they are really only needed in the proof. This would change if the statement of the theorem is to serve at the same time as definition of the constants and properties. For instance to make the theorem pseudo-constructive.

Your formulation is in the middle of all of this,

- it is a local theorem with a global Lipschitz condition, and thus slightly more restrictive than the more general formulation, especially if $U$ is not bounded,
- and it is naming the constant in the Lipschitz condition, but not with the full construction of the interval radius $τ$.

Remember that the proof of the general local theorem first selects a cylindrical domain and 1.) determines the maximum of $|f|$ over it, then restricts this to a smaller cylinder where all solutions would have to exit through the sides, then 2.) on that determines the local $y$-Lipschitz constant and then 3.) further makes the cylinder narrower so that the Picard iteration is contractive. In your formulation the first two steps are exchanged, resp. the second is left out as there is a global $y$-Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I read somewhere that the local version is more useful so I went with that one. Is my formulation still a correct statement of the PL theorem local variant?

Comment: They have both their uses. The local version is complemented by the discussion of a maximal solution and how divergence can happen or be prevented. The global version is useful for linear systems and linear DE of higher order. With the local version one can directly treat the case of continuously differentiable $f$.

Comment: Thank you again. For confirmation, is what I wrote an accurate formulation of PL local variant?

Comment: Where it says for every $x,y \in U$ in my formulation, I think it should actually be “for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^m$” since $x,y$ come from the second argument. But I am not 100% sure,

Comment: Also what exactly is $U$ in your peano and local variants?

Comment: You need $(t,x),(t,y)\in U$, one can usually say nothing about function values outside the domain, as these are undefined. $U$ in Peano is the same, it is the domain of $f$, an open set where $f$ is continuous. Yes, your formulation works, if you want to apply it you might need to reduce the domain to a bounded set, which is not too different from the more general approach.