# What does "regular enough function" mean in this context?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In ODE, there is a uniqueness and existence theorem for the first-order ODE,

$$M'(t)=f(t,M(t))$$
$$M(0)=M_0$$

The condition for $f$ to satisfy this theorem varies by text but the lecture note that I get says that $f$ has to be "regular enough." I'm very little known about regularity(I learned that if the coefficients in ODE are analytic at some point p, we call it "regular at p" and use the linear approximation to get the approximate solution). What does it actually mean and what is the definition of it?

I would appreciate any help or guidance on the reference that I can look into. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: Does your lecture note then use more than the continuous differentiability of $M$? In general you need $f\in C^{k-1}$ to get $M\in C^k$. One could also demand $f$ to be linearly bounded to get a global solution,... See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926900/picard-lindel%c3%b6f-theorem-variations/3942088#3942088 and browse the "Related" side-bar.

Comment: "Regular enough" basically means "conditions apply, but you don't need to worry about those right now".