# Proving the convergence to the global solution of Picard's method by Banach fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are the solution of the following differential equations:

$$x'=-y$$
$$y'=x$$
$$x(0)=1$$
$$y(0)=0$$

This can be solved by Picard's method:

$$x_{k+1}(t)=1+\int_0^t(-y_k(t))dt$$
$$y_{k+1}=0+\int_0^tx_k(t)dt$$

Generally, the existence and uniqueness of a **local** solution can be proved by Banach's fixed point theorem.

However, for this special case, the limit of Picard iteration is the **global** solution:

$$\cos\theta = 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2!}+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-\dots$$
$$\sin\theta = \theta -\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\dots$$

My question is: Is there a metric space which the Banach's fixed point theorem can be applied to prove the convergence of Picard's method to the global solution, in the case of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$?

Comment: There are theorems that tell you when a local solution extends to a global solution. One that applies here is that any ODE of the form $y'(t) = A(t)y(t)$ has a unique solution defined on $\mathbb{R}$. See section 2.3 (page 80) here for proofs: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Comment: See [general statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3942088/115115), [the general idea for the global variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771929/115115), [a more complete proof sketch](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1236482/115115). The special metric space is the space of continuous functions over $\Bbb R$ with the modified norm, containing those functions that are finite in this norm. Note that in any useful point norm the Lipschitz constant is $L=1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Does that norm have a name?

Comment: I have never seen a name for this norm, also not seen it outside this context. It is closely related to the Grönwall lemma, in fact if you have a time dependence of the Lipschitz constant, like $L(t)=\|A(t)\|$, you get a tighter factor by replacing $L·t$ with $\int_0^t L(t)\,dt$.