# Question about existence-and-uniquess theorem (Picard approximation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

When proving Picard approximation theorem, we always suppose $f(x,y)$ is continuous on a rectangle area, that is, $|x-x_0|\leqq a$, $|y-y_o|\leqq b $.

If we get $x$ from the whole real number line $\Bbb R$, then how can we prove that the sequence $\phi_n(x)$ converges  consistently to $\phi(x)$, because only when it is inside a rectangle area, we can prove
$$
|\phi_n(x)-\phi_{n-1}(x)| \leqq \frac{ML^{n-1}(x-x_0)^{n}}{n!} \leqq \frac{ML^{n-1}h^n}{n!},
$$
then use Weierstrass to get converge consistently. Here $h$ is $\min(b/M,a)$, $M$ is the $\max(|f(x,y)|)$ on the rectangle area.

My question is when replacing $a$ to $\infty$, how can we repeat the whole process coz now we can not use $h$ as a bound of $(x-x_0)$

$\phi_n(x)$ is Picard approximation sequence.

$\phi_n(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t,\phi_{n-1}(t))dt$

$L$ is the Lipschitz coefficient.

Comment: What is $\phi_n(x)$? What is the mathematical statement in your question?

Comment: ϕn(x) is picard approximation sequence.

Comment: To make the post self-contained, please add that into your post. How is the approximation *defined*?

Comment: Sorry, coz the whole proof is so long, I think I can not type them all on the screen.

Comment: What is your question here? Are you asking why $\phi_n\to\phi$?

Comment: I am confusing if $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$, can we prove the solution is existent and unique on it too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131107/discussion-between-andrew-ren-and-louis-pan).

Comment: The question appears to be how the local proof of Picard-Lindelöf-Cauchy-Lipschitz can be extended to a global proof. For discussions of global versions or globalization strategies see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587806/picards-existence-theorem-successive-approximations-and-the-global-solution, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347599/questions-about-the-picard-lindelöf-theorem-for-an-ode, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926900/picard-lindelöf-theorem-variations and links therein.

Comment: Please check or re-organize the statement that you want to prove. As a minimum, $f$ has to be continuous and globally Lipschitz in the second argument, that is, one Lipschitz constant $L$ for the whole domain.

Comment: Given Lip($L$) regularity, you can move in time by $L^{-1}-\epsilon$ using Picard iteration with convergence backed up by the Banach fixed point theorem. From there you can start again, and if your Lipschitz constant stays bounded, then you can hit any time horizon you want. If it doesn't, then things can break down, like in $y'=1+y^2,y(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you directly replace $a$ with $\infty$, then you lose control over the growth of the solution. Thus the usual strategy is to assume first that you can replace $b$ with $\infty$ while $a$ remains finite and show that the existence proof can be carried out for any finite $a$, thus any solution can be extended without bounds.

One usual assumption is that $f$ is globally Lipschitz continuous in the second argument $y$, one constant $L$ without any restriction to a rectangular area.

As you observed, the critical quantity is now $M$. However, $M$ is in this proof construction only ever used in the bound for $\phi_1$ for the start of the iteration, as in
$$
|\phi_1(x)-\phi_0(x)|=|\phi_1(x)-y_0|\le\int_{x_0}^x|f(s,y_0)|\,ds\le M\,|x-x_0|.
$$
As $s\mapsto f(s,y_0)$ is a continuous function, it will have a maximum $M_a$ for any finite interval $[-a,a]$, so that above upper bound holds with $M=M_a$ and the convergence of the series via Weierstrass can be proven without further restriction for $h=a$.

Proving the uniqueness of the constructed solution has now to apply some Grönwall argument, giving
$$
|\phi(x)-\psi(x)|\le|\phi(x_0)-\psi(x_0)|e^{L|x-x_0|},
$$
so that with identical initial points also the solutions have to be identical on the intersection of their domains.