# Are these versions of Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

While browsing through ode textbooks, I notice there are some slight differences in how Picard's theorem is stated and presented. I was wondering if these versions are equivalent or is one stronger than the other.

[image]

[image]

Now if I had to guess, I would say the second version is more general than the first since we are only assuming Lipschitz and not differentiability for the y variable. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The first version is also often called the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem. I've enumerated some variations in an answer to a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926900/picard-lindel%c3%b6f-theorem-variations/3942088#3942088